# Python heat map from two categorical variable columns

Tags: python, split, heatmap, categorical-data

Hi I need to plot a heat map from a data frame with only two columns.
The columns are consist of about 300 rows. each row has a user assigned category (A-E) and a score between 1-5.

I want to show the user score percentage of each category as a heatmap.

e.g.

```
    1  2   3   4  5
A  70% 10% 10% 5% 5%
B  50% 20% 10% 8% 2%
C  30% 40% 10% 10% 10%
D  10% 30% 20% 30% 10%
E  20% 20% 40% 15% 5%
```

thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

Here's my solution using numpy, pandas, and seaborn:

```py
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import seaborn
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt

# Create summaryTable
categories = np.array(['A','B','C','D','E'])
summaryTable = pd.DataFrame(index=categories, columns=np.arange(1,6))

for i in range(summaryTable.shape[0]):
    for j in range(summaryTable.shape[1]):
        df_ij = df.loc[df.Category == summaryTable.index[i]].loc[df.Score == summaryTable.columns[j]]
        numOccurances = df_ij.shape[0]
        numOccurancesCat = df.loc[df.Category == summaryTable.index[i]].shape[0]
        
        summaryTable.at[categories[i], j+1] = numOccurances / numOccurancesCat * 100
        
# Create heatmap 
summaryTable_np = summaryTable.to_numpy().astype(float)
xLabels = np.arange(1,6)
yLabels = categories
seaborn.heatmap(summaryTable_np, annot=True, linewidths=.5, square=True, 
                xticklabels=xLabels, yticklabels=yLabels,
                vmin=np.amin(summaryTable_np), vmax=np.amax(summaryTable_np), cmap='Reds')
plt.yticks(rotation=0)
```

where `df` is your data frame with ~300 rows and 2 columns and `summaryTable` is the user score percentage table.

Here is a sample heatmap: 
[image: heatmap]